# CPSchedulePowerUpAtDate on iOS iPhone SDK 4.0?

Tags: iphone, sdk, ios4, jailbreak

what's the equivalent of CPSchedulePowerUpAtDate on the iOS 4.0?

In iPhone OS 3.1.3 I could use it.

I'm getting this error:

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _CPSchedulePowerUpAtDate
>     Referenced from: /Applications/AppABC.app/AppABC
>     Expected in: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _CPSchedulePowerUpAtDate
>     Referenced from: /Applications/AppABC.app/AppABC
>     Expected in: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport

(yes, it's a private framework, but I'm not programming for the appstore.)

Thanks!